# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'count')

Tags: typescript, next.js, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm getting this "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'count')" error message when trying to use @react-three/csg.

```js
"use client";

import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { OrbitControls } from "@react-three/drei";
import { Base, Geometry, Intersection } from "@react-three/csg";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
      <Canvas>
        <ambientLight />
        <OrbitControls />
        <pointLight position={[10, 10, 10]} />
        <mesh>
          <meshNormalMaterial />
          <Geometry>
            <Base>
              <mesh position={[0, -1, 0]} rotation={[0, 45, 0]}>
                <boxGeometry args={[1, 1, 3]}></boxGeometry>
                <meshNormalMaterial />
              </mesh>
            </Base>
            <Intersection>
              <mesh position={[0, -1, 0]} rotation={[90, 0, 0]}>
                <cylinderGeometry args={[0.5, 0.5, 3, 32]}></cylinderGeometry>
                <meshNormalMaterial />
              </mesh>
            </Intersection>
          </Geometry>
        </mesh>
      </Canvas>
    </main>
  );
}
```

[Here is the codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/weathered-mountain-ftsrx9?file=%2Fapp%2Fpage.tsx&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqjv9nbu00073b6hyqpqfgzz%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqjv9nbu00023b6hegl3wvv6%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqjv9nbu00043b6hecs19aly%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqjv9nbu00063b6hc1tx9ult%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clqjv9nbu00023b6hegl3wvv6%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqjv9nbu00023b6hegl3wvv6%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqjv9nbu00013b6hz8bca170%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqjv9nbu00013b6hz8bca170%2522%257D%252C%2522clqjv9nbu00063b6hc1tx9ult%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqjv9nbu00063b6hc1tx9ult%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqjv9nbu00053b6hmeyt0zu3%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqjv9nbu00053b6hmeyt0zu3%2522%257D%252C%2522clqjv9nbu00043b6hecs19aly%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqjv9nbu00043b6hecs19aly%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqjvh76j00sg3b6hakzpj7v6%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqjvav3h00233b6h3yw3h6la%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clqjwsfhq000eehiid7ak7z8t%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqjvh76j00sg3b6hakzpj7v6%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

I'm not sure how to debug this, and find out the root cause of the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm trying to get the intersection of two geometries - but getting an error instead.